# CollectionViewSource Filtering Items

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using one collection view source bind with many ListBoxes. Each time i am going to the particular listbox Page, I want to filters CollectionViewSource items according to the requirement. So i want know about CollectionViewSource. If am Changing Filter it will Filter items with earlier Filter and This Filter or Only it will filter items with current assigned filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind all the list boxes to the same `CollectionViewSource`, then yes, updating that source will update all of the list boxes.

You might find Geoff Hudik's [WP7 In-App Searching, Filtering](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/14/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering.html) blog post useful.